# Как правильно работать с триггером таблицы базы Oracle при использовании Spring Data

Tags: java, oracle, spring-data

Для автоматической генерации id записи в базу oracle, используется встроенный триггер, ранее использовалась последовательность.

```
/**Системный идентификатор записи*/
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID_ISX", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long idIsx;
```

Как можно получить запись которую только что сохранил?
 Например, я переопределяю CrudRepository и в нем метод save(),
 затем я сохраняю новую сущность и сразу же вызываю получение послдней записи... Но если в после моей записи в этот момент таблица освобождается для записи из другого источника в эту таблицу, а мой запрос на получение созданной мной записи окажется вторым, то тогда я получу id чужой записи.

Или же, когда выполняется моя транзакция, то в момент записи таблица блокируется пока не выполняться операции в рамках моей транзакции и я буду уверен что получу достоверную информацию.

Answer (score 0):

Ничего не блокируется. Но идентификатор вы получите именно своей записи. Механизмы получения отличаются у разных СУБД